# Reloading changes very slow after update Angular from version 9 to version 15

Tags: angular

We have updated our project setup from Angular 9 to Angular 15. The serious problem with this is that reloading changes in the frontend now takes about 40 seconds and with Angular 9 version, changes were reloaded after 3 to 4 seconds. Of course, this slows us down enormously during development. Therefore, the question whether the reloading of changes can also be significantly improved with Angular 15? Reloading changes in the backend works flawlessly. But in the frontend recompiling takes about 40 seconds for each change.

The project is started with 'npm run start-dev' and this runs ng serve for the frontend and starts the backend.

Below are all the relevant files:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "webapp-projectsetup",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start-dev": "concurrently \"npm run client\" \"npm run server-dev\"",
    "start-prod": "concurrently \"npm run client\" \"npm run server-prod\"",
    "client": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "server-dev": "set NODE_ENV=development && ts-node-dev server.ts",
    "server-prod": "set NODE_ENV=production && ts-node server.ts"
  },
  "author": "XXXX",
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.13.0",
    "npm": "9.3.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@ag-grid-enterprise/row-grouping": "^27.3.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.1.0",
    "@elastic/elasticsearch": "^7.17.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.10.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
    "ag-grid": "^18.1.2",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^27.3.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^27.3.0",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "^27.3.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.2",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^0.7.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "concurrently": "^7.6.0",
    "connect-timeout": "^1.9.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "elasticsearch": "^16.7.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "fortawesome": "0.0.1-security",
    "http": "0.0.1-security",
    "log4js": "^6.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "mssql": "^7.3.5",
    "ng-bootstrap": "^1.6.3",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.3.4",
    "ngx-translate": "0.0.1-security",
    "nocache": "^3.0.4",
    "node-http-proxy": "^0.2.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "underscore": "^1.13.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.1.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^15.1.0",
    "@types/elasticsearch": "^5.0.40",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.12",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.18",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  }
}
```

angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "WebAppProjectSetup": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/WebAppProjectSetup",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "favicon.ico",
                "input": "src/",
                "output": "/"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets/",
                "output": "/assets/"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css",
              "./node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css",
              "./node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css",
              "./node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham-dark.css",
              "./node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-blue.css",
              "./node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-bootstrap.css",
              "./node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-dark.css",
              "./node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-fresh.css",
              "./node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-material.css",
              "./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": {
                "scripts": true,
                "styles": {
                  "minify": true,
                  "inlineCritical": false
                }
              },  
              "outputHashing": "none",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "dev": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ]
            },            
            "loc": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.loc.ts"
                }
              ]
            }                        
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget":"WebAppProjectSetup:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "WebAppProjectSetup:build:production"
            },
            "dev": {
              "browserTarget": "WebAppProjectSetup:build:dev"
            },
            "loc": {
              "browserTarget": "WebAppProjectSetup:build:loc"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "WebAppProjectSetup:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "WebAppProjectSetup:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "WebAppProjectSetup:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }}
  
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "useDefineForClassFields": false
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

Would be great if someone could help.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Necessary was the extension of the ng-serve call in the package.json

From:

```
"client": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"
```

To:

```
"client": "ng serve --configuration=dev --hmr --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
```